# JSON.parse("") fails with script error but not inside try/catch

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, exception

On Chrome (not on Firefox though),

```js
JSON.parse("")
```

fails with "Script error." You can reproduce it by running the script above or by running https://jsfiddle.net/xupf27nh/1/. Why the script error? There is no cors activity here...?

```js
try {
    JSON.parse("")
} catch(e) {
    throw e;
}
```

correctly prints the error message `"message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input",`. Why is it different this time? And why doesnt

```js
a.b.c.d.e.f()
```

fail with `script error`  but correctly displays the error message?

Comment: CORS? In Chrome I get `VM28:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input`

Comment: Can u paste example of your string which u need to parse ?

Comment: @phybarin I don't think he actually wants to parse something rather than understand the behaviour of uncaught exceptions.

Comment: Why do you think CORS and script error are related? Also not sure where you are getting script error. Should be SyntaxError and ReferenceError which I clearly see when I run the examples above.

Comment: An error that can be received when a string not suitable for json. In this case "" not suitable

Comment: For those confused about the question. The first code block indeed produces a "script error" on Chromium 87.0.4280.66 https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jz09h.png

Comment: @3limin4t0r I get the same in Edge Dev - different messages.

Comment: It seems https://blog.sentry.io/2016/05/17/what-is-script-error explains why wrapping into try catch make this code throw the correct error instead : It has to do with CORS. however it does not explain why behaviour is different between browses.

Comment: @JeanBouvattier awesome! Learned something today. That's worth an answer, don't you think so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Browsers intentionally hide errors originating from script files from different origins for security reasons. In this case, because of CORS setup, the error returned by `JSON.parse` is treated as a different origin and therefore hidden by your browser.

However when you encapsulate with `try\catch`, the error is thrown by your code :

```
try {
    JSON.parse("")
} catch(e) {
    // your browser see an error thrown from here : your code
    throw e;
}
```

Therefore your chrome browser does not identify the error from another origin, this is the same reason `a.b.c.d.e.f()` error is correctly displayed : it is identified as an error thrown by your code.

Note that browsers have different specifications and implementations (and bugs) of CORS policy so they may behave differently like here.

You can learn more about this specific script error here : https://blog.sentry.io/2016/05/17/what-is-script-error

Comment: Ok. But `the error returned by JSON.parse is treated as a different origin` why? I am also seeing this behavior in an environment without any foreign scripts at all. It also doesnt make sense why `JSON.parse` should somehow reside on a different origin but `a.b.c.d.e.f()` shouldn't. So as far as I understand you now, this is maybe just due to some weird browser implementation.

Comment: I really dont want to start wrapping all JSON.parse() calls (and who knows what else?) in my code in try/catch because of this, to avoid unreadable frontend error reports. I'll try to reproduce the `script error` without complicated wrappers like SO oder jsfiddle and get back here later. Thank you

Comment: I speculate `JSON` is identified as an extern module, thus the different origin for `JSON.parse`. Anyway your problems should disappears once deploying, the link will give you other solutions.